# Batch Rename at

Tags: windows, command-line

I need help with a Command Prompt Script with regards to Bulk Renaming AVI & JPG files within their folders by using their respective "Folder Names", however the JPG file named "folder" must remain unchanged.

Example Before:

C:\Temp\Videos\Terminator (1984ST)\Terminator (1984).avi

C:\Temp\Videos\Terminator (1984ST)\Terminator (1984).jpg

C:\Temp\Videos\Terminator\Folder.jpg

Example After:

C:\Temp\Videos\Terminator (1984ST)\Terminator (1984ST).avi

C:\Temp\Videos\Terminator (1984ST)\Terminator (1984ST).jpg

C:\Temp\Videos\Terminator\Folder.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with Windows PowerShell: see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/) how to open Windows PowerShell.
And try these commands line:

```
cd C:\Temp\Videos\"Terminator (1984ST)"
dir * | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "1984","1984ST"}
```

Reference: [PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/), [commands](http://ss64.com/nt/)